# Single-space regex replacement on Notepad++

Tags: sql, regex

I have a textfile of rows of values, each field delimited by a single space. The end of each row is signalled by the Windows-style {carriage return, newline}.

I would like to replace each spaces with a comma using Notepad++ but I am unfamiliar with whitespace regex on Notepad++.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s` works for me at least as a whitespace token, just as it does in normal regular expressions. A single regular space character in the replace dialog works just as well.

Comment: Also, a literal space (" ") in a regular expression will match a literal space in the file.